# Nested extends for infered type in extends block of conditional type errors

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

When using the following code (edited for simplicity) in a `.d.ts` file, `tsc` fails to compile with the error `error TS1005: '?' expected.` at the marked position:

```js
declare type BaseTest<B extends C> = ...;
export declare type Test<T extends A> = T extends (infer B extends C)[] ? BaseTest<B> : never;
                                                                    ~
```

The weird part is that the code above has been emitted (without errors) by `tsc` for a library based on the following source code (edited for simplicity):

```js
type BaseTest<B extends C> = ...;
export type Test<T extends A> = T extends (infer B extends C)[] ? BaseTest<B> : never;
```

The `extends` restriction is necessary as `B` will be passed to `BaseTest` as a generic type parameter and the generic Parameter for `BaseTest` has to extend `C`.

The source code for the library is on [github](https://github.com/pdamianik/github-action-input-parser).

- [example 1](https://github.com/pdamianik/github-action-input-parser/blob/master/lib/types.d.ts#L58) (the error also happens for all other cases of `infer ... extends ...` on this and the next line)
- [example 2](https://github.com/pdamianik/github-action-input-parser/blob/master/src/types.ts#L83)

[example usage](https://github.com/pdamianik/test-action/blob/main/src/main.ts)

I already tried using the same typescript compiler options (target, module, etc.) for both projects.

Comment: your TypeScript version needs to be > 4.7 for this to compile. See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7/#extends-constraints-on-infer-type-variables

Comment: @TobiasS. >=4.7 you mean :')

Comment: @TobiasS. thanks its working now. I wonder why it worked previously for the library and not for the usage example because I wasn't using ts >= 4.7 in either of them.